# What is a regular expression to return the substring between two characters in a longer string?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string in Perl like: "**`Full Name (userid)`**" and I want to return just the userid (everything between the "`()`"'s).

What regular expression would do this in Perl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will match any word ([`\w`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes)) character inside of "`(`" and "`)`"

[`\w`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes) matches a word character (alphanumeric or _), not just `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` but also digits and characters from non-roman scripts.

```
my($username) = $str =~ /\((\w+)\)/;
# or
$str =~ /\((\w+)\)/;
my $username  = $1;
```

If you need it in a `s///`, you can get at the variable with `$1` or `\1`.

```
$str =~ s/\((\w+)\)/$1:\1/; # pointless example
```

If you want to capture all possibilities these would work better:

```
my($username) = $str =~ /\(([^\)]+)\)/;
# or
my($username) = $str =~ /\((.+?)\)/;
```

If your regexp starts to get complicated, I would recommend you learn about the [`/x`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) option.

```
my($username) = $str =~ / \(  ( [^\)]+ )  \) /x;
```

---

Please see [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), for more information.

If you are just beginning to learn regexps, I would recommend reading [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Comment: Surely if he wants what's *between* the parentheses, it would be /(\(\w+\))/ ?

Answer (score 4):

Escape the brackets, capture the string in-between. Assuming user ids consist of `\w` characters only:

```
my ($userid) = $str =~ /\((\w+)\)/ ;
```

`m//` in list context returns the captured matches.

More information on capturing can be found in

`C:\>` [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches)

Comment: So just by putting the extra parenthesis it returns the value?  (The (\w+) vs just \w+ ?

Comment: That is called capturing. If the match is evaluated in list context (e.g. `my ($userid) = ` as opposed to `my $userid = `, all the captured matches will be returned. In this case, there is only one.

Answer (score 3):

When you search for something between brackets, e.g. '< > [ ] ( ) { }' or more sophisticated such as xml/html tags, it's always better to construct your pattern in the way:

```
opening bracket, something which is NOT closing bracket, closing bracket
```

Of course, in your case 'closing bracket' can be omitted:

```
my $str = 'Full Name (userid)';
my ($user_id) = $str =~ /\(([^\)]+)/;
```

Comment: umm, doesn't the non-greedy operator (the ? in .*?  in RC's example) eliminate the need for this pattern? The non-greedy operator will cause the regex to match at the first closing parens, rather than the ultimate one. Your approach is more compatible, since not all regex implementations have a non-greedy operator, but for those that do (like Perl), I find it easier to read than your negation pattern. Just a style thing....

Comment: This approach is safer. If you want use it inside some more complex regular expression you can be easy bitten by back-trace if you rely on non-greedy pattern.

Comment: Actually it's not only safer, but more efficient, because backtracking to satisfy non-greediness is eliminated

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has been said: If you happen to *know* that your string has exactly this format, you can also do without regexp. If your string is in `$s`, you could do

```
chop $s; # throws away last character (by assumption must be closing parenthesis)
$username=substr($s, rindex($s,'(') + 1);
```

As for the regexp solutions, can you be sure that the full name can not contain also a pair of parentheses? In this case, it might make sense anchoring the closing ')' at the end of the pattern:

```
/ [(]     # open paren
 ([^(]+)  # at least one non-open paren 
  [)]     # closing paren
  $       # end of line/pattern
/x && $username = $1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get anything between the parentheses and not just alphanumeric and _.  This may not be an issue, but \w will not get usernames with dashes, pound signs, etc.

$str =~ /\((.*?)\)/ ;